# php/pdo INSERT function not displaying field content in myphpadmin

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I'm trying to insert content from my form into my database. I'm using twitter bootstrap 3 to layout my website but here is the form;

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="assets/mailreview.php" role="form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Submit you're review</legend>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="firstname">First Name:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surname">Last Name:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Job Title:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="New kitchen.." class="form-control input-md" type="text">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="brief">Description:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="brief" name="brief">please type you're review here</textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submitbtn">Submit:</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button id="submitbtn" name="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

As you can see I have set the submit action to respond to mailreview.php on doing so I receive no errors(after several and i mean several) however the form properties will not display in myphpadmin. It does insert a new row but not the field content.

here is mailreview.php

```
    <?php
    include_once("config.php");

$sql = "INSERT INTO review (firstname, lastname, email, title, brief) values(:firstname,:lastname,:email,:title,:brief)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['surname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':brief', $_POST['brief'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```

any advice or support would be very grateful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing colons on your list of values.

Change this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO review (firstname, lastname, email, title, brief) values(firstname,lastname,email,title,brief)";
```

to:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO review (firstname, lastname, email, title, brief) values(:firstname,:lastname,:email,:title,:brief)";
```

Comment: i attempted this Mark, however it returns an error now; 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstname' cannot be null' 

Having looked at the db i haven't set this column as 'null'

Comment: Do you want to allow null values in the `firstname` field? If so, then you will need to set the column to null in the db. Otherwise, you need to ensure that `$_POST['firstname']` is not null before attempting the `INSERT`. I would run the query again, making sure that all the $_POST fields have values. This will confirm that the query works.

Comment: I attempted this also Mark, could it be as i have two more columns before 'firstname' i have 'id' and 'date' is it trying to insert into id as thats the first column rather then missing them two and a going to the third that is 'firstname'

Comment: The syntax I have provided is correct - you need the `:`s. Manoj is also correct - you need that closing `"`. There must be another problem. Can you print out the full PDOException to get a better idea of what is happening?

Comment: THanks for you're help. This is now working correctly with the advice you gave. many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing `"` for `form` `class`, because of this your form data are submitted as `get` not `post`

Replace

```
<form class="form-horizontal method="post" action="assets/mailreview.php" role="form">
```

With and try

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="assets/mailreview.php" role="form">
```

Comment: thank you for noticing this, however it still inserts a blank row

Comment: See other answer given by Mark M, you are missing `:` in your values

Comment: Make sure you are using both solutions, mine and Mark M, as You are missing closing `"` for `form` `class` and `:` in your values

Comment: I have used both solutions- marks results in errors and no entry of a row. you're resulted in css changes.